# How to remove programmatically a tab bar item created in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app is a tab bar based app with 5 tab items relation ship segue to view controllers. I would like to build 3 different view controllers with different sizes (iPhone 5, 6 and 6+). My ideas is to bind the 3 different view controllers within xcode graphical and remove the two not needed with the specific iPhone at runtime.

```
UITabBar *oldbar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBar *newbar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,oldbar.frame.size.width,oldbar.frame.size.height)];
NSMutableArray *olditems = [[oldbar items] mutableCopy];
[olditems removeObjectAtIndex:2];
[olditems removeObjectAtIndex:3];
NSArray *newitems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:olditems];
[newbar setItems:newitems animated:false];
[oldbar addSubview:newbar];
```

The problem is that xcode shows the "more.." tab because in xcode there are not 5 but 7 tab items?

Is there a better way to program what I need?

Comment: Build the tab bar controller in completely in code. Then you have full controller over what is shown.

Comment: It's already in your's code `[newbar setItems:newitems animated:false];` but why create new tabbar and add it as subview? Just setItems in your old tabbar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have an example code for it? How can I link programmatically to a view controller?